# Since redis 6 use multi thread now, does lettuce better use connection pool now?

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis, lettuce

According to lettuce wiki
https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Connection-Pooling-5.1

It doesn't need connection pool in general, but so does redis(before 6).

Since redis 6 use multi thread now, does lettuce better use connection pool too?

Comment: definitely Lettuce needs connection pooling. tried to use it in my app (with many requests), and with Lettuce (with one connection) performs way worse than Jedis ...